# Setting JavaScript variable to relative image file

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have recently built a small game as part of a learning project.
The images we use in the game are linked to an external site:

```js
let botDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/robot.svg";
let beachDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/beach.svg";
let spaceDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/space.svg";
const closeDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg";
```

```html
<div class="door-row"> 
   <img id="door1" class = "door-frame" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg" alt="door1">;
    <img id="door2" class = "door-frame" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg" alt="door2">;
    <img id="door3" class = "door-frame" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg" alt="door3">;
 </div>
```

I wanted to adapt the game and amend the image locations to files that are on my PC.
However in doing so the game fails and/or images do not load.

My bug testing essentially shows
1. linking to another random external image (off wiki) fails to render on screen but the game still functions when clicking on the broken link icons.
2. when adding relative path to the images, they become static and nothing happens:

```js
let botDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/robot.svg";
let beachDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/beach.svg";
let spaceDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/space.svg";
var closeDoorPath = "./Resources/Batman.svg";
```

```html
    <div class="door-row"> 
      <img id="door1" class = "door-frame" src="./Resources/Batman.svg" alt="door1" width="200px" height="200px">;
      <img id="door2" class = "door-frame" src="./Resources/Batman.svg" alt="door2" width="200px" height="200px">;
      <img id="door3" class = "door-frame" src="./Resources/Batman.svg" alt="door3" width="200px" height="200px">;
      
    
    </div>
```

3. i have also amended the relative path to it full location "C:/ etc", but this also fails.

Where do i start in resolving this please?

Comment: Whats the folder structure like. Where are the images located in reference to this html file?

Comment: Project folder holds 1 x html, 1 x css, 1 x js and a 'Resources folder'..  The image are within the resources folder